# Jquery insert list element with sortable position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

How to use jquery to make it so that clicking items from either of the two lists will move the selected item into the other list.

When moving items to the other list, the new ordering should be first numerically based on the items number (data-value), and then the left item followed by the right item.

For example, if you were to click "left item 2", that item should be removed from the left list, and the right list should then show Right item 1, Left Item 2, Right Item 2, Right Item 3, Right item 4, Right item 5

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
           <div class="row">
               <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-6">
                   <div class="well">
                       <ul class="my-list my-list-left">
                           <li data-value="1">Left Item 1</li>
                           <li data-value="2">Left Item 2</li>
                           <li data-value="3">Left Item 3</li>
                           <li data-value="4">Left Item 4</li>
                           <li data-value="5">Left Item 5</li>
                       </ul>
                   </div>
               </div>
               <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-6">
                   <div class="well">
                      <ul class="my-list my-list-right">
                           <li data-value="1">Right Item 1</li>
                           <li data-value="2">Right Item 2</li>
                           <li data-value="3">Right Item 3</li>
                           <li data-value="4">Right Item 4</li>
                           <li data-value="5">Right Item 5</li>
                      </ul> 
                   </div>
               </div>
           </div> 
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a good start...

you can find how to make the listener events and the `jQuery` selectors.

You can also add a logic to manipulate the html element and sort them.

```js
$('ul.my-list-left ').on('click','li',function () {
     var  total =  $('ul.my-list-right li').length;
     if(total ===0){
         $('ul.my-list-right').append($('ul.my-list-left li').eq($(this).index())) 
     }else{
         var data_value = parseInt($(this).attr('data-value'));
         
         var position = total<data_value?total-1:data_value-1;
         $('ul.my-list-right li').eq(position).after($('ul.my-list-left li').eq( $(this).index())) 
     }
 });

 $('ul.my-list-right ').on('click','li',function () {
     var  total =  $('ul.my-list-left li').length;
     if(total ===0){
         $('ul.my-list-left').append($('ul.my-list-right li').eq($(this).index())) 
     }else{
         var data_value = parseInt($(this).attr('data-value'));
         
         var position = total<data_value?total-1:data_value-1;
         $('ul.my-list-left li').eq(position).after($('ul.my-list-right li').eq( $(this).index())) 
     }
 });
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
           <div class="row">
               <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-6">
                   <div class="well">
                       <ul class="my-list my-list-left">
                           <li data-value="1">Left Item 1</li>
                           <li data-value="2">Left Item 2</li>
                           <li data-value="3">Left Item 3</li>
                           <li data-value="4">Left Item 4</li>
                           <li data-value="5">Left Item 5</li>
                       </ul>
                   </div>
               </div>
               <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-6">
                   <div class="well">
                      <ul class="my-list my-list-right">
                           <li data-value="1">Right Item 1</li>
                           <li data-value="2">Right Item 2</li>
                           <li data-value="3">Right Item 3</li>
                           <li data-value="4">Right Item 4</li>
                           <li data-value="5">Right Item 5</li>
                      </ul> 
                   </div>
               </div>
           </div> 
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like this, though I'd spend more time cleaning it up.

You need to move the clicked element from the source list to a target list, and then sort the target list based on the attribute.

The following Javascript does this both ways.

```
var moveToListAndSort = function(source, target, attribute) {
    attribute = attribute || 'data-value';  

    // Whenever a list item is clicked in the source list
    $(source).on('click', 'li', function() {
        // Remove the clicked list item from its current list
        $(this).remove();

        // Append it to the target list
        $(target).append($(this));

        // Sort the target list based on an attribute
        $(target).children('li').detach().sort(function(a, b) {
            var valueA = a.getAttribute(attribute);
            var valueB = b.getAttribute(attribute);

            var sortA = a.getAttribute('data-sort');
            var sortB = b.getAttribute('data-sort');

            // Compare the value attributes of the two list items
            if (valueA > valueB) {
                return 1;
            }

            if (valueA < valueB) {
                return -1;
            }

            // The value attributes are the same, so compare the
            // sort attributes
            if (sortA > sortB) {
                return 1;
            }

            if (sortA < sortB) {
                return -1;  
            }

            return 0;
        }).appendTo(target);
    });
};

moveToListAndSort('.my-list-left', '.my-list-right');
moveToListAndSort('.my-list-right', '.my-list-left');
```

I had to add a second attribute, `data-sort` to each list item to determine what to sort by *after* the value, which is hard-coded.

The function optionally accepts a third parameter, `attribute`, in case you want to perform the initial sort by a different attribute.

Ideally the sorting would be extracted to its own function so that it can operate in isolation.

```js
var moveToListAndSort = function(source, target, attribute) {
    attribute = attribute || 'data-value';  
    
    $(source).on('click', 'li', function() {
        $(this).remove();

        $(target).append($(this));

        $(target).children('li').detach().sort(function(a, b) {
            var valueA = a.getAttribute(attribute);
            var valueB = b.getAttribute(attribute);

            var sortA = a.getAttribute('data-sort');
            var sortB = b.getAttribute('data-sort');
          
            if (valueA > valueB) {
                return 1;
            }

            if (valueA < valueB) {
                return -1;
            }

            if (sortA > sortB) {
                return 1;
            }
            
            if (sortA < sortB) {
                return -1;  
            }
          
            return 0;
        }).appendTo(target);
    });
};

moveToListAndSort('.my-list-left', '.my-list-right');
moveToListAndSort('.my-list-right', '.my-list-left');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
            <a style="float: right; margin-top: 30px;" href="index.html">&laquo; Back to the interview question list</a>
            </h1>
            <h4>jQuery DOM manipulation and event handling.</h4>
            <p>Open up <code>test1.html</code>, and add in some Javascript code to make it so that clicking items from either of the two lists will move the selected item into the other list.</p>
            <p>When moving items to the other list, the new ordering should be first numerically based on the items number (<code>data-value</code>), and then the left item followed by the right item.</p>
            <p>For example, if you were to click "left item 2", that item should be removed from the left list, and the right list should then show <code>Right item 1, Left Item 2, Right Item 2, Right Item 3, Right item 4, Right item 5</code></p>
            
            <hr />
            
           <div class="row">
               <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-6">
                   <div class="well">
                       <ul class="my-list my-list-left">
                           <li data-value="1" data-sort="1">Left Item 1</li>
                           <li data-value="2" data-sort="1">Left Item 2</li>
                           <li data-value="3" data-sort="1">Left Item 3</li>
                           <li data-value="4" data-sort="1">Left Item 4</li>
                           <li data-value="5" data-sort="1">Left Item 5</li>
                       </ul>
                   </div>
               </div>
               <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-6">
                   <div class="well">
                      <ul class="my-list my-list-right">
                           <li data-value="1" data-sort="2">Right Item 1</li>
                           <li data-value="2" data-sort="2">Right Item 2</li>
                           <li data-value="3" data-sort="2">Right Item 3</li>
                           <li data-value="4" data-sort="2">Right Item 4</li>
                           <li data-value="5" data-sort="2">Right Item 5</li>
                      </ul> 
                   </div>
               </div>
           </div> 
        </div>
```